# Guidance on grouping equal sets of numbers, so each group has a similar average

Tags: javascript, sorting

**Goal:** I am trying to build teams of 5 people. Each person has an integer elo (rank). My goal is to make all the teams as equal/fair as possible, by having the average elo of each team be as close as possible to one another.

**Approach:** My initial thought was to go through the list of elos and take the highest elo player and pair it with the lowest elo player. I did this twice (*4 people on each team*), sorting the array of teams after each loop by the teams median elo. On the final loop, I took the last set of elos (*5th teammate*) and put the highest players with the lowest team averages.

After my 3rd loop I noticed the biggest jump in the elo difference between the lowest team and highest team.

**Question:** I am wondering if my 3rd loop's logic is the main problem, or if this whole approach in general is bad. I have tried searching for algorithms about this like the "partition problem", but am having little success implementing it into my functions.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/aanders50/8m7m9tdw/3/

*Omitted visual code that is in the JSFiddle above*

```
var elos = ['big array of integers'];
var teams = [];     //store teams
var teamCount = 0;  //number of total teams
var teamSize = 5;   //number of players on each team

function myFunction() {
 teamCount = elos.length / teamSize;
 teams.length = 0;
 var i = 0;

 //order default list of elos
 elos.sort();

 //add 1 high and 1 low elo to each team
 for (i = 0; i < teamCount; i++) {
   teams[i] = new Array();
   teams[i][0] = elos.splice(0,1);
   teams[i][1] = elos.splice(elos.length-1,1);
 }

 //first sort by median elo
 sortTeams();
 $("#dif1").html(getMedian(teams[teams.length - 1]) - getMedian(teams[0]));

 //add another high and another low elo to each team
 for (i = teamCount-1; i > -1; i--) {
   teams[i][2] = elos.splice(0,1);
   teams[i][3] = elos.splice(elos.length-1,1);
 }

 //second sort by median elo
 sortTeams();
 $("#dif2").html(getMedian(teams[teams.length - 1]) - getMedian(teams[0]));

 //add highest remaining elo to lowest median elo team
 for (i = 0; i < teamCount; i++) {
   teams[i][4] = elos.splice(elos.length-1,1);
 }

 //3rd and final sort by median elo
 sortTeams();
 $("#dif3").html(getMedian(teams[teams.length - 1]) - getMedian(teams[0]));

 //display results
 printTeams();
}

//sort each team by average elo
function sortTeams() {
 teams.sort(function (a, b) {
  a = getMedian(a);
  b = getMedian(b);

  if (a > b) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a < b) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
  });
}

//get average elo of each team
function getMedian(numberArray) {
   var sum = numberArray.reduce(function(a,b) {
     return Number(a) + Number(b);
   });
   return (sum / teamSize);
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-shop_scheduling may or may not help. The general question (partitioning 'n' elements into 'k' sets such that the sum of the sets are as close to each other as possible) appears to be a well-known, but difficult to solve (ie, NP complete) problem.